# Java name generator variable is already defined in method main(String[])

Tags: java

I am new, having a problem with my code. I wonder how will I be able to print a variable after the if statements. When I don't put the variable before the if statement it says that it's not initialized. here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class NameGenerator {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
Scanner getInput = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("What's the first letter of your first name? ");
String name = getInput.nextLine();

String xmas2;

if (name.equalsIgnoreCase ("a"))  {
    String xmas2 = "Christmas";
    
} else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase ("b")) {
    String xmas2 = "Merry";
    
} else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase ("c")) {
    String xmas2 = "Santa";
    
} else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase ("d")) {
    String xmas2 = "Chocolate";
    
} else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase ("e")) {
    String xmas2 = "Tinsel";
    
} else if(name.equalsIgnoreCase ("f")) {
    String xmas2 = "Yule";
}

System.out.println("Hey " + xmas2);

}
```

}

Comment: `String xmas2 = "Christmas";` should be `xmas2 = "Christmas";`. You don't want to *redeclare* `String xmas2` variable again, just to assign value to already existing variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you assign variable only 1 time **" String xmas2 = null;"**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner getInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What's the first letter of your first name? ");
        String name = getInput.nextLine();

        String xmas2 = null;

        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
            xmas2 = "Christmas";

        } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
            xmas2 = "Merry";

        } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
            xmas2 = "Santa";

        } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("d")) {
            xmas2 = "Chocolate";

        } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("e")) {
            xmas2 = "Tinsel";

        } else if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("f")) {
            xmas2 = "Yule";
        }

        System.out.println("Hey " + xmas2);

    }
}
```

**Output**

```
What's the first letter of your first name? 
a

Hey Christmas
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that class members are automatically initialized for you by the compiler but local variables are not.  The compiler is issuing a warning to highlight the fact that you may encounter odd behavior if you do not populate the local variable prior to de-referencing it. Assign null to it initially and the warning goes away.

```
String xmas2 = null;
```

You can also move the logic here into a separate method which returns a value which you assign to initialize the variable.  In the following I swap the if-else blocks for a switch and throw an Exception if the provided letter is not handled by the switch.  Moving things into methods helps to define a unit of work.

```
public class Practice {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    String xmas2 = interpretName(name);
    ...
  }

  private String interpretName(String name) {
    String lower = name.toLowerCase();
    switch (lower) {
      case "a": return "Christmas";
      case "b": return "Merry";
      case "c": return "Santa";
      case "d": return "Chocolate";
      case "e": return "Tinsel";
      case "f": return "Yule";
      default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unhandled name: "+name);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to compile your code snippet, you need to initialize the variable `xmas2` by using the assignment operator `=` after its declaration with one of the options below, before using the variable for any statements or calculations after that.

1. Null: `String xmas2 = null;`
2. Empty string: `String xmas2 = "";`
3. Or any String value: `String xmas2 = "Any string";`

You may ask, why even the assignment `String xmas2 = null;` is able to fulfill the complaint `Variable 'xmas2' might not have been initialized` from the compiler. Does the `String xmas2;` declaration already do the same thing by automatically assigning it to a default value of `null`?

Then the answer is **No**. Java compiler **will not automatically assign** it - your **local variable**.

In Java, **unassigned class member variables** are automatically initialized to a default value, which in case a `String`, it should be assigned to `null`. Therefore if you have an unassigned class member, it will be able to compile successfully, due to the default value.

But **unassigned  local variables** (Your `xmas2` variable) are not assigned to any value until you manually assign it to a value (include `null`), therefore the compiler will give you a compile error.